# docker-compose -p up alternative in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We are using `docker-compose` with dash and wanted to switch to `docker compose` without dash as it prevents to install `docker-compose` additionally. But we are using the `-p` flag when we `up` containers to rename the stacks that we are running. `-p` does not seem to exist on `docker compose` so I was wondering: How can I rename the stack with `docker compose`? The documentation does not mention something similar: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/

So how can this

```
docker-compose -p my-stack up -d
```

become this?

```
docker compose -p my-stack up -d
```

Comment: What is the OS of machine Docker installed on? Does creating an alias solve your problem? It's one way

Comment: but I want to use docker directly, an alias would not help here. It is not about the syntax, i just want to use `docker compose` like `docker-compose`. This occurs on my windows dev machine and the linux build server.